# python dataframe appending columns horizontally

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, concatenation

I am trying to make a simple script that concatenates or appends multiple column sets that I pull from xls files within a directory. Each xls file has a format of:

```
Index    Exp. m/z   Intensity   
1        1000.11    1000
2        2000.14    2000
3        3000.15    3000
```

Each file has varying number of indices. Below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import tkinter.filedialog

full_path = tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir='.')
os.chdir(full_path)

data = {}
df = pd.DataFrame()

for files in os.listdir(full_path):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(full_path, files)):
        df = pd.read_excel(files, 'Sheet1')[['Exp. m/z', 'Intensity']]
        data = df.concat(df, axis=1)

data.to_excel('test.xls', index=False)
```

This produces an attributerror: DataFrame object has no attribute concat. I also tried using append like:

```
data = df.append(df, axis=1)
```

but I know that append has no axis keyword argument. df.append(df) does work, but it places the columns at the bottom. I want something like:

```
Exp. m/z   Intensity       Exp. m/z   Intensity  
1000.11    1000            1001.43    1000
2000.14    2000            1011.45    2000
3000.15    3000
```

and so on. So the column sets that I pull from each file should be placed to the right of the previous column sets, with a column space in between.

Comment: Only typo - not `df.concat(df, axis=1)` but `pd.concat(df, axis=1)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you need `append` `DataFrames` to list and then [`pd.concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
dfs = []
for files in os.listdir(full_path):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(full_path, files)):
        df = pd.read_excel(files, 'Sheet1')[['Exp. m/z', 'Intensity']]
        #for add empty column 
        df['empty'] = np.nan
        dfs.append(df)
data = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought I got used to pandas with appending/concatenating, but never thought about doing it this way.

Comment: a quick question: is there a way to add empty column in between files when concatenating?

Comment: I think simpliest is add it in loop before append(dfs), I edit answer.